# In JS, ow can I get index of an element in 2d array when the array is represented on a web page?

Tags: html, arrays, angular

[image]

I'm making an othello game board on a HTML page using Angular. The board is made of a 2d `number` array and I show this using `<table>` tag on a web page. The following is what I've done.

A HTML Page(app.component.html):

```
<table>
    <tr *ngFor="let line of board">
        <td *ngFor="let cell of line" (click)="click(cell)">
            <div class="black" *ngIf="cell == 1">●</div>
            <div class="white" *ngIf="cell == 2">●</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The array initialized in JS(app.component.ts):

```
board =[
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
    [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
]
```

Empty cells have the value of `0`, while black and white have `1` and `2` respectively. The next thing I have to do is to get the index of the clicked cell, check if it's empty or not.

If every cell has its own value to identify, I can easily figure out which cell is clicked using `.indexOf`, but all the empty cells have the same value of `0`.

One idea I have is to declare an array of an object containing an `id` field or something like below:

```
export class Cell{
    status: number//0, 1 or 2
    id: number//0 ~ 63
}
```

Can I use some better idea beside this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get each index of the `rows` and `cells` and pass them into the function `click`. This will passes the current index of the row and cell, which was clicked.

```
<tr *ngFor="let line of board; let lineIndex = index">
    <td *ngFor="let cell of line; let cellIndex = index" 
        (click)="click(cell, lineIndex, cellIndex)">
        <div class="black" *ngIf="cell == 1">●</div>
        <div class="white" *ngIf="cell == 2">●</div>
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: you are awesome. btw, is that `index` automatically created when i call `*ngFor`? i ran this code and all those indices properly get values starting with 0.

Comment: Yes, they automatically created when you use `*ngFor`